# Node.js server.get() TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    app = express(),
    server = http.createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server), //pass a http.Server instance
    fs = require('fs');

server.listen(8008);

// routing
server.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/chat.html');
});
```

I have this code which creates a server. When I run this I get the following error: TypeError: undefined is not a function

```
server.get('/', function (req, res) {
       ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rexhi\Desktop\private_mess\app.js:11:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

What is wrong here? I'm new to Node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.get(req,res)` function belongs to an instance of `express`. Thus, you should do:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    ..
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you are trying to use express to handle your routing, if that is the case then you want to use `app.get()` not `server.get()`. So in your case something like

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/chat.html');
});
```

Take a look at the express routing reference for more info - http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `app.get()` instead of `server.get()`

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/chat.html');
});
```